# What is the Ruby Way to write to multiple files

Tags: ruby

What is the "Ruby Way" to have an 'if' statement write to one of two possible files based on how the expression evaluates?

In Perl, I would do something like the following to loop through an array checking for keys in a hash. The output would write to either 'existing-keys.txt' or 'missing-keys.txt' as appropriate.

```
giant_hash = { 'k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2', 'k3' => 'v3' }
check_array = ['k1', 'k3', 'k4']

f1 = File.open('existing-keys.txt', 'w')
f2 = File.open('missing-keys.txt', 'w')

check_array.each do |check_key|
    if giant_hash.has_key?(check_key)
        f1.puts check_key
    else 
        f2.puts check_key
    end
end

f1.close
f2.close
```

That works, but I'm new to Ruby and have run into lots of times when there are more Ruby-like ways to do things. Is there a more Ruby Way to write multiple files?

Comment: I don't get how you could do much better than this. What would you consider more "Rubyish"?

Comment: The word you're looking for may be "idiomatic"

Comment: stack overflow isn't a good place for questions whose answer is primarily opinion based.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: There may not be a more Rubyish way. Since I'm relatively new to the language, I'm trying not to take anything for granted. I'm not looking for opinion as much as making sure there isn't some standard convention that I haven't discovered yet. Other examples I've seen of using blocks with files are different from what I've done in other languages. Just trying to figure out if there is something like that in this case.

Comment: maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a more on-topic site, even though it's not as high-traffic at the moment

Comment: @JustinL. - I didn't know about that Code Review site. That looks great. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not too much of a performance overhead to iterate twice (most likely, it isn't), you can just do it twice -- the simplest way would be

```
File.open('existing-keys.txt','w') do |f|
  f.puts check_array.select { |k| giant_hash.has_key? k }
end

File.open('missing-keys.txt','w') do |f|
  f.puts check_array.reject { |k| giant_hash.has_key? k }
end
```

Alternatively you could use (and I think this is the best way)

```
existing, missing = check_array.partition { |k| giant_hash.has_key? k }

File.open('existing-keys.txt','w') { |f| f.puts existing }
File.open('missing-keys.txt','w') { |f| f.puts missing }
```

which is a bit cleaner/more expressive, and probably gets rid of some of the overhead in going through check_array twice.

If you are in 1.9.3+ you can use `File.write`

```
File.write('existing-keys.txt',existing * "\n")
File.write('missing-keys.txt',missing * "\n")
```

but I don't think it's that necessary/as idiomatic.  Still an option.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same. I guess you could take advantage of that fact if statements in Ruby actually return values, though it may become less readable. You could also use a ternary (you could do that in Perl too):

```
check_array.each do |check_key|
  (giant_hash.has_key?(check_key) ? f1 : f2).puts check_key
end
```

By the way, use 2 spaces for indentation in Ruby, always. This is a *much* stronger convention in Ruby than in other languages, so follow it.